# Is it possible to grep only one column and print other SELECTED output at the same time

Tags: linux, bash

Title my be ambiguous.  Here's an example of what I'm asking.

```
#ls -l
```

prints me out something like this

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5110 2011-10-08 19:36 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5111 2011-10-08 19:38 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5121 2011-10-08 19:36 5110.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5122 2011-10-08 19:38 5111.txt
```

Say I wanted to use grep to find all filenames containing  `'511'` and print out the size/filename of the file.

How do I grep for filenames `'511'`, still print the filesize, and not have the output contain the top two rows.

thank you very much SO, reading man pages hasn't helped me on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
pax:~$ echo '
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5110 2011-10-08 19:36 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5111 2011-10-08 19:38 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5121 2011-10-08 19:36 5110.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5122 2011-10-08 19:38 5111.txt
' | awk '{if (substr($8,1,3)=="511"){print $5" "$8}}'

5121 5110.txt
5122 5111.txt
```

It simply checks field 8 (the filename) to see if it starts with "511" and, if so, prints out fields 5 and 8, the size and name.

Comment: Holy cow.   I was trying to use awk but didn't know how to do the if statement.  Very useful information. Thank you!

Comment: This does not work correctly for files with spaces in their name.  It's not too hard to fix.

Comment: Also the substr only looks for matches at the beginning of the file name, not anywhere in the name.  Again, this is not too hard to fix, but parsing `ls` output should be avoided.

Comment: A simplier solution: `awk '$8 ~ /.*511.*/ {print $5" "$8}'`

Comment: uzsolt.  What is this called?  How can I get more information on this syntax and what it all means.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name '*511*' -printf "%s\t%p\n"
```

Comment: Maybe add `-maxdepth 0` to prevent `find` from going into subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the filename you want to filter on, why do you list other files in the first place?

```
ls -l *511* | cut -c23-30,48-
```

or even with `awk`;

```
ls -l *511* | awk '{ $1 = $2 = $3 = $4 = $6 = $7 = ""; print }'
```

However, the output from `ls` is not entirely robust, so you should avoid processing it directly.

```
perl -le 'for (@ARGV) { print ((stat($_))[7], " $_") }' *511*
```

The `stat()` system call returns the raw information displayed by `ls` in a machine-readable format.  Any tool which gives you access to this information is fine; it doesn't have to be Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass `ls` and just use `bash`'s filename `glob`:

```
for f in 511*
do
    echo $f $(stat --format '%s' $f)
done
```